# WebTestRequest.ReportingName is ignored when using VS Team Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, performance-testing

I have the following method in my custom `WebTest`:

```
private WebTestRequest CreateRequest(CommandInput command)
{
    WebTestRequest request = new WebTestRequest(URL);
    request.ReportingName = command.CommandName;
    request.Method = command.HttpMethod;

    // ...

    return request;
}
```

On my `GetRequestEnumerator` I am calling the method like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
     return new CommandInput[]
     {
         new CommandInput() { CommandName = "configuration", HttpMethod = "POST" },
         new CommandInput() { CommandName = "login", HttpMethod = "POST" },
         new CommandInput() { CommandName = "quick_view", HttpMethod = "GET" },
         new CommandInput() { CommandName = "esign_document", HttpMethod = "POST" }
     }.Select(CreateRequest).GetEnumerator();
}
```

**Note: The original code is more complicated than this, but it is irrelevant**.

This is working fine when running the load test on my local machine:

You can see that each request is being identified by the value of `ReportingName` property

[image: Local summary]

However, If I run the load test on Visual Studio Online services, requests are grouped by URL instead of the value on `ReportingName`:

[image: Cloud summary]

Requests are being grouped as `command {GET}` and `command {POST}` because the URL is the same for every request on my test case (`https://test.xxxx.com/api/command`), only differing by HTTP method on some of them.

I searched for hours on the Internet and only managed to find this open thread about it on MSDN:

[Reporting Name does not show up in Page Results of Online Load Test](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/1c5a1954-a182-4b04-9a82-b03e148dd843/reporting-name-does-not-show-up-in-page-results-of-online-load-test?forum=TFService)

What is happening?

Comment: I can get the same behavior as you and have submit a feedback for this issue on MS connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3102026

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Glad to hear it's not something mine. Thanks for the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue will be fixed by 10/16.

> Posted by Shiva [MSFT] on 9/28/2016 at 8:59 AM
>
> Thanks for reporting this issue. We have fixed the issue and would
>   deploy it by 10/16.